# Xml definition containing multiple instances of a type?

Tags: xml

I want to create an xml document that has multiple instance of a type, not sure what's the proper way to do this:

```
<farm>
  <horses>
    <horse name="jo"></horse>
    <horse name="bill"></horse>
  </horses>
</farm>
```

or should I skip the  tag and just do this:

```
<farm>
  <horse name="jo"></horse>
  <horse name="bill"></horse>
</farm>
```

which way is correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's xml, you're free to choose whatever you like best :)

Seriously - both are ok; but think about who you want to please.

As a programmer that would need to consume XML, I would like the first form better.
As an editor that would need to manually create XML I would like the second form better.

I guess i would probably settle for the first form.

Comment: Ok cool I will go with the first choice since I am going to be parsing it, thanks.

Comment: Ok, good! If you want to open another can of worms, ask what is best, using an attribute for the `<horse>`'s name, or an attribute like you do now :)

Comment: uhm...I mean, "a *child element* or an attribute", sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how way 1 is better than way 2.

Since there is a separate *type* (that is, separate node name) for horses, an additional wrapper, `horses`, does not make much sense to me. It would, it horses needed to be separated into several groups, say, `horsesToKeep` and `horsesToSell`.

Comment: Format 1 clearly puts all the horses together and makes it clear that they belong together. Format 2 suggests that it may be possible to have one `horse`, followed by one `cow`, and then another `horse`.